# GetLegendGraphic issues

Tags: qgis, wms

I'm pretty new to actually using QGIS. I'm currently trying to figure out how to use the WMS feature. I'm currently trying to add a legend to the BGS maps i've added through WMS. I'm a bit confused to why it isn't working.

I'm aware you need to change the html address according to this

[image]

So i'm currently trying to do that

https://map.bgs.ac.uk/bgs_wms/legends/digmapgb50.gif?&SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetLegendGraphics&LAYERS=BGS.50k.Bedrock&VERSION=1.3.0&CRS=EPSG:3857

Although it just comes like this.

[image]

I'm preparing for an interview so I want to present some maps on this survey area and do assessment of the geology/hydrogeology etc.

Comment: The beginning of your url points directly to the gif file https://map.bgs.ac.uk/bgs_wms/legends/digmapgb50.gif?. Is the service open? Could you add a link to GetCapabilities? However, maybe the message is corrects and service does not supply any other legend for that layer.

Comment: Cheers for getting back to me. This is the GetCapabilities link from the BGS website https://map.bgs.ac.uk/arcgis/services/BGS_Detailed_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&. This is the website also https://www.bgs.ac.uk/technologies/web-map-services-wms/web-map-services-geology-50k/

Comment: I'll try using getcapabilities instead if that's what you mean, i'm pretty new to this but i guess everyone has to start somewhere right

Comment: GetCapabilities sends a document that is telling info about the WMS service, including the URLs that should be used for GetLegendGraphics. Some tutorials about WMS basics might be better starting point.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a very bright WMS server, if you look at the [`getCapabilities` document](https://map.bgs.ac.uk/arcgis/services/BGS_Detailed_Geology/MapServer/WMSServer?service=WMS&version=1.3.0&request=GetCapabilities&) that gives you information about it, you will see each layer has the same legend:

```
<LegendURL width="307" height="337">
    <Format>image/gif</Format>
    <OnlineResource xlink:href="https://map.bgs.ac.uk/bgs_wms/legends/mass_movement.gif" xlink:type="simple"/>
</LegendURL>
```

which displays the image you've seen:

[image: An image saying "No legend is supplied for this layer. Use the available query tools to get information about features at a given point]

So adding parameters to that URL won't help you.